# C++ a value of type cannot be assigned to an entity of type

Tags: c++

```
while (gameon = true) {
  char ch = _getch();
  if (ch == 'd') {
    move = move + 1;
    ch = "";
  }
}
```

I get this error and kind find anything to fix this on this forum

Comment: `== true` instead of `= true`. Or just `while (gameon)`

Comment: `while (gameon = true)` is 99% a typo, it should be `while (gameon == true)`. Whether or not this is the source of your error, I don't know, because you didn't present [mcve]

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `ch = ""` probably causes the error though.

Comment: @RadoslavVoydanovich Yep, you're right, I missed it. Would be a lot easier if OP posted actual error message :)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen True.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen the title is sort of the error message

Answer (score 2):

With `ch = ""`, you are attempting to assign a string to a `char` type. This is what the compiler is complaining about.

Since you are setting `ch` in each iteration of the loop, it is not necessary to try to clear the variable.

Also, you need to fix your while loop: replace `= true` with `== true`)